# pdfbox.util.ImageIOUtil.writeImage issue

Tags: java, pdfbox

There is an issue with PDFbox going on here.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.ImageIOUtil.writeImage(ImageIOUtil.java:197)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDJpeg.createImageStream(PDJpeg.java:190)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDJpeg.<init>(PDJpeg.java:150)
```

Our current setup is 2 servers with 2 JVMs for each server running over **Websphere 8.5** and **Java 6**.

When we restart the JVMs the issue seems to be resolved, but after few hours we get the same exception.
The application is using **PDFBox v1.8.8**

Here is a piece of the code:

```
ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
document.addPage(page);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedImage convertedFile = tiffToBufferedImageJAI(file);
PDXObjectImage img = new PDJpeg(document, convertedFile);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.drawXObject(img, 0, 0, 550, 800);
contentStream.close();

document.save(baos);
document.close();
baos.flush();

return baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Can you expand your question such that we know where the problem occurs in your code?

Comment: Hi, Looks like this piece of code is throwing the exception: PDXObjectImage img = new PDJpeg(document, convertedFile);

Comment: Please retry with the current version, which is 1.8.13. Btw if the source is a TIFF file, compressing it as jpeg is usually a bad idea. Better use one of the two other classes for images, i.e. PDPixelMap or PDCcitt.

Comment: Have you monitored memory consumption? As you get that behavior after some hours of runtime, some kind of resource depletion sounds plausible...

Comment: Yes, i did. i haven't seen any issue related to memory/CPU.

Comment: I had another look at PDPixelMap - it doesn't make the call that throws an NPE in your current code. And an additional goodie will be that you'll get nicer images, i.e. without JPEG artefacts.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the ImageWriter below was registered but would not start correctly:

com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageWriterSpi

So, when `ImageWriterIterator.next()` was called, `spi.createWriterInstance()` was throwing a silent IOException and a null was being returned:

```
public ImageWriter next() {
        ImageWriterSpi spi = null;
        try {
                spi = (ImageWriterSpi)iter.next();
                return spi.createWriterInstance();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                // Deregister the spi in this case, but only as a writerSpi
                theRegistry.deregisterServiceProvider(spi, ImageWriterSpi.class);
        }
        return null;
}
```

The reason why `spi.createWriterInstance()` was failing was:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/medialib/codec/jpeg/Encoder
```

Adding `-Dcom.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib=true` to the JVM startup made the offending ImageWriter not to be registered anymore.

Comment: Great find. I have created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3739 to catch this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the PDFBox code it would appear that the problem is caused because there are no writers for JPG images available at that time (see line ImageIOUtil line 197 and trace back to [line 184](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/1.8.8/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/util/ImageIOUtil.java#L184)).

I would suggest that something in your app server is calling ImageIO.scanForPlugins() with a constrained classpath of some kind and mutating the available writers, or something else is getting in and fiddling.

Comment: kindof scary that `writers.hasNext()` is `true` but `writers.next()` is null shortly after that?!

Comment: Completely agree; I'd have expected a `ConcurrentModificationException` or something if there is a rescan taking place on a different thread. Difficult to see what else is going on here without getting some kind of remote debugging and digging in when it happens

Comment: The issue is happening because the writers.hasNext() is true but writers.next is null. The issue has been fixed locally by adding the following JVM parameter: Dcom.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib=true